# Why back button is called twice from Unity code?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my android app there is a menu which opens a small unity game. Game plays on `UnityPlayerActivity`  The problem is when i press system back button it is being triggered twice i guess. Because after `UnityPlayerActivity` closed, the activity before it also closed. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

This is `UnityPlayerActivity`. Handled back press event in `onKeyUp`

```
public abstract class UnityPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents {

protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
protected String updateUnityCommandLineArguments(String cmdLine) {
    return cmdLine;
}

// Setup activity layout
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String cmdLine = updateUnityCommandLineArguments(getIntent().getStringExtra("unity"));
    getIntent().putExtra("unity", cmdLine);

    if (mUnityPlayer == null) {
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this, this);
        onCreateWithUnity(mUnityPlayer);
        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    }
}

// When Unity player unloaded move task to background
@Override public void onUnityPlayerUnloaded() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

// Callback before Unity player process is killed
@Override public void onUnityPlayerQuitted() {
}

@Override
public void setIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    super.setIntent(newIntent);
    mUnityPlayer.newIntent(newIntent);
}

// Quit Unity
@Override protected void onDestroy () {
    mUnityPlayer.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

// If the activity is in multi window mode or resizing the activity is allowed we will use
// onStart/onStop (the visibility callbacks) to determine when to pause/resume.
// Otherwise it will be done in onPause/onResume as Unity has done historically to preserve
// existing behavior.
@Override protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (!MultiWindowSupport.getAllowResizableWindow(this))
        return;

    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

@Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (!MultiWindowSupport.getAllowResizableWindow(this))
        return;

    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}

// Pause Unity
@Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    MultiWindowSupport.saveMultiWindowMode(this);

    if (MultiWindowSupport.getAllowResizableWindow(this))
        return;

    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

// Resume Unity
@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (MultiWindowSupport.getAllowResizableWindow(this) && !MultiWindowSupport.isMultiWindowModeChangedToTrue(this))
        return;

    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}

// Low Memory Unity
@Override public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
}

// Trim Memory Unity
@Override public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL){
        mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
    }
}

// This ensures the layout will be correct.
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// Notify Unity of the focus change.
@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}

// For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
// Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

// Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
@Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
}
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
/*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
```

}

Comment: I’m assuming it’s because you’re injecting event into the unity player, and its also propagated by the caller class .

Comment: Try to disable (prevent) default behavior when back button event is propagated

Answer (score 0):

Rather than injecting the event directly into the Unity player, you can achieve the desired functionality by implementing a mechanism to pass a **boolean flag** whenever the back button is pressed.

Just as an experiment, have you tried using a boolean flag in such a way that prevents that specific block of code from firing twice. For example in the `onKeyUp`:

```
private boolean isBackButtonHandled = false;

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && !isBackButtonHandled) {
        isBackButtonHandled = true;
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I've used onKeyDown instead of onKeyUp and it seems the problem is solved.